# choice between in-memory cache and database, any other in-memory options php

Tags: php, memcached

I have to do a lookup on around 160K records where in data is in the form of 
id     and we need to get the rows for which a given value is in the range of range1 and range2, so so far its a between query that we use.

I started using memcache yesterday, which finds out if a perticular row against the given value is in the memcache and if not than it puts it in memcache by taking it from the db.

I am not sure what's the order of lookup in memcache itself, is it o(1) or o(n), I know dbsearch can at best get me o(log n) , and i am thinking to keep another layer in-between of some other in-memory object[i can't think off right now, but i certainly don't want to use the sessions to keep the table in-memory], and rather get the data from this in-memory object, and if not found in it, then go to database.

PS - my db table hardly goes through any changes.

so the order i am thinking of is 
Lookup in memcache
  if not found (lookup in in-memory - do a binary search on the array), and add to memcache
      if not found lookup in db, add to in-memory and add to memcache.

Am I thinking in right direction

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Memcached is very fast and lookups are o(1), not o(n) so you are best off just using memcached and some backend database. Consider the scenario you proposed above. Having a secondary cache that is slower than memcached in the middle will only increase latency of requests since you will now potentially have to ask 3 places for some data instead of just two. Also since memcached is going to be faster than the in memory database solution your better just giving all of your extra memory to memcached. Another thing to consider too is the management overhead of adding an extra tier for your application.